# How do I make KDE Plasma Handbook pages less white?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, accessibility, plasma-5

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

I'm more comfortable reading text on a dark background rather than on a white background.

The various Handbook pages provided by KDE Plasma in the Help menu have a mainly white background. The image below is an example:

[image: Kate Handbook]

I would like the change the white background to something less bright like the area to the left of and above the actual Handbook contents.

Answer (score 1):

By some testing, I identified two files

- /usr/share/doc/HTML/en/kdoctools5-common/kde-docs.css and
- /usr/share/doc/HTML/en/kdoctools5-common/kde-default.css

One can backup these files and then edit them suitably. An example, again using the Kate Handbook. The foreground image is *before* and the background image is *after* editing:

[image: Before and after editing the css files]

(A caveat is that updates will overwrite these files.)